# How to change the alpha of a bitmap font in libgdx

Tags: java, bitmap, libgdx

I want to make a message box that fade when you accept but I don't know how to change the alpha of a font,

here is how I do my font:

```
white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/font/whitefont.fnt"),false);
white.setUseIntegerPositions(false);
white.setScale(0.025f);
white.draw(batchHUD, message.nom+":", 1000*0.1f+(1000*0.8f*0.3f), 625*0.1f+(1000*0.8f*0.625f*0.5f*0.1f)+1000*0.2f);
```

Can anyone help me ? :) I'm sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Comment: Don't know about libgdx, but generally you change the alpha of the *drawing context*, not the things you draw. With plain Java2D for example you would use Graphics2D.setComposite([instance of AlphaComposite]) *or* setColor([Color with alpha]).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
white.setColor(1, 1, 1, <alpha>);
```

This will change the alpha of the font for all following draws. So you would probably want to set it to full opaque again once you draw that message.

```
white.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks you, I hadn't thought about it !