# Best method of setting text alpha in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I'm currently resetting a GlyphLayout every frame to propagate the opacity changes in BitmapFont, however this seems to be dragging down performance a lot since it needs to calcualate the width and height every time.

Is there a better way to change text opacity?

```java
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    bitmapFont.setColor(1, 1, 1, opacity);
    glyphLayout.setText(bitmapFont, text); // <-- performance bottleneck

    bitmapFont.draw(batch, glyphLayout, posX, posY);
}
```

Comment: Are you changing "text" value each time you call setText()? Because if you don't, AFAIK you can just call setColor() with the new opacity without calling setText() each time. Please check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100529/how-to-change-the-alpha-of-a-bitmap-font-in-libgdx

Comment: @GadWissberg I am not changing the text value in setText(). However, if I don't call setText() the opacity doesn't get updated. I think this has to do with the text being a GlyphLayout and not a string, as in the question you linked.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but BitmapFontCache seems like what you might need. According to the documentation:
"Caches glyph geometry for a BitmapFont, providing a fast way to render static text. This saves needing to compute the glyph geometry each frame."
And it provides setAlphas(float alpha).
Take a look here:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFontCache.html

Comment: @GadWissberg It seems that the font's cache is not used when using GlyphLayout. Setting `bitmapFont.getCache().setAlphas(opacity)` has no effect.

@Squiddie Thanks for the hint, that'll help much.